# Android notifications not being destroyed

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-broadcastreceiver

i'm having issues with destroying notifications in android.
My app generates some notifications at specific times, and i'd like to have the automatically removed after some time (60 seconds).
The notifications are created by a `BroadcastReceiver` that catches a broadcast created by the `alarmManager` and then extracts informations from the broadcasted `intent` and creates the notification.
Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't. 
 I think it's because android terminates some process or something like that, but i couldn't find anything online.
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notification);

    Log.d("AlarmReveiver","id della notifica: " + String.valueOf(notificationId));

    //cancella la notifica quando l'orario è passato
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    long delay = 60*1000;
    final int lullo = notificationId;
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("Handler","id della notifica: " + String.valueOf(lullo));
            notificationManager.cancel(lullo);
        }
    },delay);

    notificationId++;
```

Note that `notificationId` is a `static int`; i guessed that i could use a static variable to have the number of notifications created so far in order to avoid mess with notification IDs, but i saw that this counter is being reinitialized to 0 after a while.

Does anyone know a better way (a way that works everytime lol) to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assume an app will remain resident.  You definitely can't count on the app remaining around long enough for the handler to process your message.  That means that between any two calls to a BroadcastReceiver, it can lose all statics.  Instead, of a Handler, use an AlarmManager alarm and put the if to cancel into the intent.

As an aside, I happened to publish my Timer class today that simplifies working with alarms.  Check out http://gabesechansoftware.com/timers-in-android/

Comment: that's what i was suspecting. Well thanks, i'll take a look to your class and fix everything.
Thank you!